# Filter several values and make a df from each of them

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I have three columns that basically are Country, Year, and Value.
I am trying to extract a dataframe for each of the unique countries. I am using the `dplyr` library like:

```
USA<-filter(df, Country=="USA")
```

I can filter all of the countries like that, but doing so seems like a very repetitive task, so I am trying to find a way of doing it more efficiently.

I am thinking in a `For` cycle but I don't really know how to script it. Here is what I tried.

```
for(i in unique(df$Country)){
  i<-filter(df, Country==i)
}
```

It actually generates a df but it only includes the observations for the last element in the `unique(df$Country)` part.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and some reproducible data so individuals can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant answer, but you could use `split` to put each group (i.e., country) into a list of dataframes. Then, you can add them to your global environment.

```
# This will give you list of dataframes by country.
list_data <- split(df, df$Country)

# Assign names to each dataframe based on country.
names(list_data) <- paste0("df_", names(list_data))

# Then, add each dataframe to your local environment.
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Or if you want to stick with a `for` loop, then you can do this:

```
for(i in unique(as.character(df$Country))) {
    nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")
    assign(nam, df[df$Country==i,])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd give a +1 but I can't bc I'm only level 11 in reputation